# Spring data native query with pageable SQL grammar error

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I am trying to use spring data with native SQL and pageable on `spring-data 2.5.0` and PostgreSQL database.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY rank DESC)," +
        "t.id, " +
        "FROM table t WHERE t.x > 0 ",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Object[]> getT(Pageable pageable);
```

But I am getting a SQLException. The result SQL is

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY rank DESC),t.id FROM table t WHERE t.x > 0 , t.y desc limit 20
```

Where its clearly visible whats wrong, the spring-data wont add ORDER BY clause to the SQL, probably because of presence of ORDER BY clause for dense_rank(). If I remove that dense selection, everything works fine.

**Is there any possibility to achieve this use case using spring-data? Maybe some possible workaround? I want to use whole Pageable object (so page size, offset and sort)**

Comment: Instead of Page<Object[]> try Page<Object>

Comment: @AjayKumar thanks for response but thats not the case and did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of trying and searching for answer I´ve found the solution, more likely the workaround. **Adding ORDER BY 1** at the end of the query will cause that spring-data will place the `, order_column ASC/DESC LIMIT X OFFSET Y` after that `ORDER BY 1` (which will not modify the result anyhow).

So the result should be

```
@Query(value = "SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY rank DESC)," +
        "t.id, " +
        "FROM table t WHERE t.x > 0 ORDER BY 1",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Object[]> getT(Pageable pageable);
```